# Adjacent JSX in React Native - error

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have this in my **React Native** code, I am trying to parse through some API data.

```
        {this.state.articles.map(article => (
     <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: article.urlToImage}}
    />

<Text style={styles.article}  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(article.url)} >{article.title}</Text>
```

and every time I run it I get a error that says:

```
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
```

I have no idea what to do, can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the `.map` call can only return one element at a time. Because the JSX-compiler sees two adjacent elements (`Image` and `Text`), it throws the mentioned error.

The solution would be to wrap the two components in a view

```
{this.state.articles.map(article => (
  <View style={{ some extra style might be needed here}}>
     <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: article.urlToImage}}
    />
    <Text style={styles.article}  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(article.url)} >{article.title}</Text>
  </View>
)}
```